# How to change default local repository path in Phabricator?

Tags: phabricator

I'm trying to migrate my current Phabricator deployment (which is a Ubuntu VM) to a docker based container.

According Phab's documentation, I should use the following command line:

```
bin/config set --database repository.default-local-path /my/new/path
```

The command above fails with:

```
Usage Exception: Config key "repository.default-local-path" is locked and can 
only be set in local configuration. To learn more, see "Configuration Guide: 
Locked and Hidden Configuration" in the documentation.
```

When I try the command above **without** `--database`, it changes the `local.json` and successfully. However, it seems that properties in stored in DB have precedence over properties defined in JSON file. Therefore, the change made to JSON file has no effect.

If this is not a bug, how do I change `repository.default-local-path`? If it is bug, is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think "locked" configuration options are ever meant to be set at the database level. This value should be provided in the local config.

Assuming that you have a value set in the database that is interfering with your local config, I'd say that is a bug. The easiest workaround that I know of is to unlock the config option by editing phabricator source. What you need to do is as follows:

1. Unlock the config option. To do this, change the source code from `setLocked(true)` to `setLocked(false)` on line 25 of [PhabricatorRepositoryConfigOptions.php](https://github.com/phacility/phabricator/blob/master/src/applications/repository/config/PhabricatorRepositoryConfigOptions.php).
2. Set a value for `repository.default-local-path` in `local.json` as you already managed to do with `bin/config set` (leaving off the `--database` argument)
3. Delete the database value with the following command: `bin/config delete --database repository.default-local-path`
4. Once everything is set correctly, you can revert your change to PhabricatorRepositoryConfigOptions.php which will restore the option to the locked state.